# unable to load error 500 calling wcf service from dojo

Tags: wcf, dojo

Im calling my wcf service from dojo and am getting the unable to load error 500.  When I test the service using WCF test client in visual studio it works fine.  I'm making the call to WCF Service using dojo xhr get:

Module calling service:

```
 define(['dojo/store/Memory', 'dojo/_base/xhr', "dojo/data/ObjectStore"],
  function (Memory, xhr, ObjectStore) {
     return {
         GetReaches: function (url) { //url is: "http://localhost:54052/FormTest/proxy.ashx?http://localhost:57735/Service1.svc/GetReaches/"
             xhr.get({//get data from database
                 url: url,
                handleAs: "json",
                load: function (result) {
                ReachData = result.GetReachesResult;
                },
                error: function (err) { }//500 error caught

            });
        } //GetReaches
    }

});
```

I'm not passing any parameters to the service so it cant be a wrong data type being passed to the function.  Any ideas of what else could be the problem?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work, I had left this important item out of the web.config file:

```
<services>
      <service name="SARIService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SARIService.IService1"     behaviorConfiguration="web">

        </endpoint>

      </service>
    </services>
```